# how to create a serverless endpoint in sagemaker?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker

I followed the aws documentation ( https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/serverless-endpoints-create.html#serverless-endpoints-create-config) to create a model and to use that model, i coded for a serverless endpoint config (sample code below) ,I have all the required values  but this throws an error below and i'm not sure why

parameter validation failed unknown parameter inProductVariants [ 0 ]: "ServerlessConfig", must be one of : VairantName, ModelName, InitialInstanceCount , Instancetype...

```
response = client.create_endpoint_config(
   EndpointConfigName="abc",
   ProductionVariants=[
        {
            "ModelName": "foo",
            "VariantName": "variant-1",
            "ServerlessConfig": {
                "MemorySizeInMB": 1024,
                "MaxConcurrency": 2
            }
        } 
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using **old boto3** version. `ServerlessConfig` is a very new configuration option. You need to upgrade to the latest version (1.21.1) if possible.

Comment: I'm doing this via lambda, with and import boto3 in my python code

Comment: @ozil boto3 in lambda is limited. It is not like the "real" boto3. You can check what version you have using `print(boto3.__version__)`. You have to bundle your own boto3 or use container lambda with new boto3.

Comment: thanks, can you point to me any examples on how to use real boto3

Comment: @ozil The easiest way is to add it as a layer. There are prebuild public layers here (https://github.com/keithrozario/Klayers) which include boto3. You have to find boto3 layer arn for your region and python version, and add it to your function. I see it still not the newest version possible, but maybe it is new enough.